# Добавить действие на кнопку в Админке Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Подскажите пожалуйста как в админку django добавить на существующую кнопку дополнительное действие
Находящиеся по пути : Проект\ptik\management\commands\tb.py

do_send_r

```
@log_errors
def do_send_r(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    ID = Ptikname.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0].id
    # ID = ID + 1
    print("ID", )
    update.message.reply_text(
        text=f'Последняя петиции : http://10.32.8.196:8000/about/{ID}\n',
    )
```

Модель куда надо добавить

```
class Ptikname(models.Model):
def get_image_path(self, filename):
    filename = self.street + '.' + filename.split('.')[1]
    return "{0}/{1}".format(self.street, filename)

date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, verbose_name="")
street = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="Улица")
status = models.ForeignKey(Status, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Статус", default=1)
view = models.ForeignKey(ViewTicket, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Вид заявки", default=1)
comment_author = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Комментарий автора")
comment_ingeneer = models.TextField(verbose_name="Комментарий", null=True, blank=True, )
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, verbose_name='Картинка', null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.street

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Имя петиции'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Имена петиций'

    ordering = ['-date', ]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: переопределить метод save в модели?